# fast data entry UI patterns

Tags: website-design, web-app, grid, data-tables, type

I am working on a web app that helps people manage their finances.

the app requires users to manually enter key financial transactions on a weekly basis, and there is a strong requirement to make the process as short and friendly to users.

which would be a better approach to this problem -

1. display a data grid, where the user enters the data and uses the
   keyboard to switch from one data field to the next
2. display a modal window with a form to take in user data
3. another solution?

Comment: in my experience with banking, few people are going to take the initiative to manually enter this type of data--especially when it already exists elsewhere. This is why products like Mint are popular...it eliminates the entire data entry hassle.

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem should be rethought at a deeper level. It sounds like you hare asking users to do quite a bit of management an application that is supposed to be helping them with management. Requiring users to perform a weekly chore, negates the value of your app.

In other words, there is not proper UX for making users do chores. Don't make users do chores. You will have to find another source for your data, or your app is likely to fall into an existential crisis that could be fatal.

Cheers!